# How do I disable commands for only 1 or 2 opped players (like worldedit and vanish)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I'm co-owner of a mc-server and the owner want's to make some of his friends **op**,
so they have access to all commands. But is there a way to take some permissions away for an opped player, without doing it for all the opped players (like me)

Server version: Spigot 1.8.x (for version 1.7.x - 1.8.x)

We use **permissionsex**. so what do i have to enter to take /vanish away?

```
permissions:
- ?
- ?
```

Plugins: Essentials,pex,multiverse,silkspawners,worldedit,worldguard and some wands

Comment: don't op them, or use a permission plugin (if you still have a bukkit server)

Comment: What plugin do you use to allow the vanish command?

Comment: Doesn't PermissionsEX support `deny` permissions? You could just allow them to do `'*'` (anything) but then deny them a few things? As deny overrides any allow.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to take op away from them, then give them the following permission nodes using `/pex user <user> add <permission>`:

First, give them `*`. This allows them to "use" any permission node.

Then, give them `-essentials.vanish.*`. This overrides the previous node, preventing them from using vanish.

Comment: I do believe that method only work with group manger whenever I gave them * it became the almighty ruler, and took over everything

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a plugin such as [Disable Commands Plus](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/disablecommandsplus/) to give certain players specific permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PEX plugin installed, generally you can use the - in the command to take commands away.
The best way to check that is to enable debug on a user (such as yourself) via the console:

```
/pex user <user> toggle debug
```

Then do the command in-game and see the checks that are being done to execute the command.
If you have something like nocheatplus enabled it will spam the console, so disable those plugins first.

Then you can enter that command with a - into your permissions file BELOW the place where it is enabling the command for the user. You can also test a timed permission from the console with

```
/pex user <user> timed add <permission> [lifetime] [world]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using McMyAdmin like me, you're in luck! First, go to Configuration and find the 'Export Permissions', then select 'PermissionsEX(supports Multiworld)'. Next, click Users & Groups from the left and from there you can configure every aspect of a group(chat color, chat prefix and suffix, color in chat, what commands it can use, what worlds can it access...) and the configuration will automatically be exported for PEX(or any other plugin you selected before).